# Преобразование функции к элементарному типу

Tags: javascript, функции

Я знаю, что если вы в JS создаете объект, то можно сделать так:

```
var obj = {
    toString: function () {
        return "мой обьект"
    }
};
```

При этом:

```
alert(obj); // Выводит "мой обьект"
```

Вопрос, как после объявления функции, чтобы вызов её без `()` возвращал не код функции, а то, что вам нужно т.е.:

```
function myFunc(){
    // Здесь секретный код
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы `alert(myFunc);` выводило не `function myFunc(){//Здесь секретный код}`, а то, что захочу я, например, строку "Моя секретная функция"?

Comment: alert(myFunc()); -- не то?

Comment: НЕТО! Я же написал надо toString а не return вы сначала JavaScript выучите а потом минусуйте!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myFunc(){
    myFunc.toString = function(){
        return "Моя секретная функция";
    }
};
myFunc();    
alert(myFunc);
```

Comment: Спасибо я пытался использовать this а только счас понял что он меняется в зависимости от вызова и надо было использовать имя ф-ции